# Copy text drawn on TImage to another TImage

Tags: delphi, copy, vcl, drawtext, timage

The following is done by using Delphi 5, for your information.

I have a small issue with copying the content of one `TImage` to another.

The first `TImage` contains drawn text that I have loaded from a text file. See the below code:

```pascal
function TMainForm.GetText(Img: TImage; v: string; dosize: boolean): boolean;
  var f:extended;
    p:timage;
    fl: textfile;
    s, t:string;
    crect:Trect;
    ds: Longint;
    ws: widestring;
begin
  v      := GetImgFile(v);
  if not fileexists(v) then
    result := false
  else try
    p := img;
    dosize := dosize and img.Stretch;
    AssignFile(fl, v);
    reset(fl);
    crect                := p.ClientRect;
    p.canvas.Font        := Refline.font;
    p.canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    p.canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;
    p.Canvas.Font.Size   := 8;
    p.canvas.FillRect(crect);
    ds                   := DT_NOPREFIX or DT_EXPANDTABS or DT_WORDBREAK;
    while not eof(fl) do begin
        Readln(fl, s);
        t := t + s;
    end;
    ws := StrToWide(t);
    DrawTextW(p.canvas.Handle, pwidechar(ws), length(ws), crect, ds);
    result := true;
  except
    result := false;
  end;
end;
```

The line `v := GetImgFile` receives the complete path to the text file.

`img` is the `TImage` that I have placed on the form. By using `DrawTextW`, I can draw the text on this `TImage`.

Before that, I have prepared a `TRect` for the `TImage` with the following code:

```pascal
myimage.tag                   := 1;
myimage.canvas.Brush.Color    := clBtnFace;
myimage.canvas.Brush.Style    := bsClear;
myimage.Canvas.Font           := refline.font;
crect2                        := Rect(myimage.left,myimage.top,myimage.left + myimage.width,myimage.top + myimage.Height);
myimage.canvas.FillRect(crect2);
myimage.visible := GetText(MyImage, copy(ws, 4, length(ws)), copy(ws, 2, 1) = 'p');
```

This part works, and this shows my text in the `TImage`.

Now, I have another `TImage` named `myimage2`, and I want to copy the drawn text into this `TImage`.

I am having issues with the copying.

I tried the easy way by using: `myimage2.picture := myimage.picture`.

I have tried to assign the image from `myimage` to `myimage2`.

The last thing I have tried is a `CopyRect` function:

```
myimage2.Canvas.CopyRect(crect3,myimage.Canvas,crect2);
```

Where `crect2` is the Rect from `myimage`, while `crect3` is the Rect from `myimage2`.

All 3 of the above possibilities have failed to copy the drawn text to the 2nd `TImage`.

I am obviously doing something wrong here, and it might be something very small, but I am not seeing the issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Solution found!

It helps making sure myimage2.visible is set to true...
Then using

```
myimage2.picture := myimage.picture;
```

the drawn text is copied...

Comment: 1. `TCanvas` has a `TextOut` method. E.g. `Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.TextOut(10, 10, 'Sample Text');`
2. `myimage2.picture := myimage.picture;` copies pointer, not the content. To copy content you should probably use `Image2.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(Image1.Picture.Bitmap);` Both images may be invisible.

Comment: @OldSkull I also thought that setting TImage.Picture directly would just copy the pointer, but having looked at the code, it actually does call Assign. I could have sworn that direct assignment just copies the reference, but even in Delphi 6, Assign is used by the method of the property setter. Weird.

Comment: @TByte, thank you. Indeed an assignment is performed. I apologize for misleading